# Confused about assigning integer as value of element

Tags: java, eclipse

I am currently working on a project for my java class and I am having a lot of trouble with this specific part. How do I "assign randomNumber as the value of the current element within ageArray"? thank you

```
public class SortAndSearch {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        
        String[] ageArray = new String[10];
        ArrayList<Integer> ageArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>(); 
        int randomNumber;
        
///////////////////// PART A /////////////////////
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            randomNumber = (int)(Math.random() * 20) + 1;
            
            /* #3: Assign "randomNumber" as the value of the current element within ageArray */
        }
```

Comment: why is `ageArray` a `String` array?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You should convert int to String

```
 ageArray[i]=randomNumber+"";
```

or

```
ageArray[i]=Integer.toString(randomNumber);
```

or

```
ageArray[i]=String.valueOf(randomNumber);
```